# find and create a new array just with one sort of value and eliminate duplicates (if many)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to find a method for sorting an array by uuid and eliminate the duplicate.

For exemple i have a array like this :

```
const x = [
{id: 1, uuid: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx, content: 'string'},
{id: 2, uuid: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx, content: 'string'},
{id: 3, uuid: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx, content: 'string'},
{id: 4, uuid: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx, content: 'string'},
{id: 5, uuid: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx, content: 'string'},
{id: 6, uuid: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx, content: 'string'},
{id: 7, uuid: yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy, content: 'string'},
{id: 8, uuid: zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz, content: 'string'}
]
```

And i'm trying to find a simple way for making this in result :

```
const x = [xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx, yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy, zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz]
```

I know it's maybe basic but my brain is off i guest ...

Thanks !

Comment: CAn you please show us what have you tried?

Comment: What does this have to do with _sorting_? You apparently want a completely different structure as result, which means this is _not_ sorting.

Comment: ok give me a second i will update

Comment: `[...new Set(x.map(({uuid}) => uuid))]`

Comment: that will not return X times the uuid with xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx value ?

Comment: combined with @CBroe recommended duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, but i used a string type for uuid:

```
[...new Set(x.map(e => e.uuid))].sort()
```

Comment: This solution won't work if the order of `xxxx...` and `yyyy...`changes. OP has asked `sorting an array by uuid`

Comment: You would have to use a sort() afterwards, I'll edit it asap, using phone currenly

Comment: I've edited the solution and It will work as expected